# Escape spaces in PowerShell and cmd

Tags: powershell

I have a PowerShell script that is calling an .exe from the command line to create an XML file and then the PowerShell script is reading that file.

The problem is if I have a *space* in the file path I need to wrap in in double quotes to pass it to the command line. When I do that the PowerShell command tries to read the double quotes as part of the file path. Is there a way to escape the spaces that will work for both passing it to the command line and using commands inside PowerShell?

It seems silly to have to pull out the double quotes for one command and leave them in for another.

The issue is with the [Get-Content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Get-Content) line not liking the double quotes.

```
$outputpath = '"C:\Users\bob\Desktop\output new.xml"'
Start -FilePath $sqlpackage -ArgumentList "/action:DeployReport /SourceFile:$dacpacpath /Profile:$profilepath /OutputPath:$outputpath" -NoNewWindow -Wait

[xml]$xmldocument = Get-Content -Path $outputpath
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Deadly-Bagel almost had it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35631113/escape-spaces-in-powershell-and-cmd/35631837#35631837) I think. Don't use double quotes in $outputpath to keep Get-Content happy, but add them in your argument list string.

Be sure to escape with backtick `.  In fact you might just want to do that with all the paths:

```
$outputpath = 'C:\Users\bob\Desktop\output new.xml'
Start -FilePath $sqlpackage -ArgumentList "/action:DeployReport /SourceFile:`"$dacpacpath`" /Profile:`"$profilepath`" /OutputPath:`"$outputpath`"" -NoNewWindow -Wait

[xml]$xmldocument = Get-Content -Path $outputpath
```

Comment: MIght be easier to use single quotes inside the double. No need to escape at that point. `/SourceFile:'$dacpacpath'`

Comment: @Matt It will work only if `$sqlpackage` program accept single quote as valid quote character.

Comment: Adding the double quotes in the ArgumentList and escaping it worked fine. @Matt the single quotes did not work.

Comment: Straight up, PowerShell is horrible.

Answer (score 1):

`-ArgumentList` accepts `String[]` so try the following:

```
$outputpath = "C:\Users\bob\Desktop\output new.xml"

Start -FilePath $sqlpackage -ArgumentList @("/action:DeployReport", "/SourceFile:$dacpacpath", "/Profile:$profilepath", "/OutputPath:$outputpath") -NoNewWindow -Wait
```

I suspect passing it all as one parameter causes it to be confused.

Comment: Sorry, the issue is on the next line with Get-Content not liking the double quotes.

Comment: Ahh my apologies, I did not read the question carefully enough ^^